# MVC4 Nested ViewModel Binding does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

i have an outerViewModel and inside of it two ViewModels,
when i try to bind innermodel i get null for all the properties...

here is the code:

```
**Models.cs**

public class OuterModel
{
    public FirstInnerModel firstInnerModel;
    public SecondInnerModel secondInnerModel;
}

public class FirstInnerModel
{
    public string Title;
}

public class SecondInnerModel
{
    public string Title;
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ActivateFirst", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {

               @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <fieldset>

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstInnerModel.Title)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstInnerModel.Title)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>          model.firstInnerModel.Title)
                    </div>
                    <p>
                       <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                    </p>
                 </fieldset>
        }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        var model = new OuterModel()
        {
            firstInnerModel = new FirstInnerModel(),
            secondInnerModel = new SecondInnerModel()
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void ActivateFirst(FirstInnerModel ggg)
    {


    }
```

ggg.Title returns null...

Anyone? help!

Comment: If you pass in the `OuterModel` to `ActivateFirst` do you get your data?

Comment: hi! :). no... both firstInnerModel and secondInnerModel are null

Comment: You might need to have a hidden field on your form for the `OuterModel` so it can be passed back to controller.

Comment: in this example if i pass the outerModel to the controller did not work... but in my original project it did :) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit the form it will be posting the OuterModel to the controller so you would need to do something like:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public void ActivateFirst(OuterModel ggg)
    {
        var whatever = ggg.FirstInnerModel.Title;

    }
```